# Undefined index: l in MPDF

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

When checking the output of the html content it seems to look okay. But when trying to get PDF result from Mpdf in Yii2 PHP, it is giving error.

PHP Code:

Code 1:

```
    $content = 'HTML CODE';
    $pdf = new Mpdf();
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('../styles.css'); // external css
    $pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $pdf->WriteHTML($content);

    try{
        return $pdf->output();
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception($e, 500);
      }
```

Code 2:

```
$content = 'HTML CODE';
$pdf = new kartik\mpdf\Pdf([
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'content' => $content,
    'filename' => 'PdfFile',
    'cssFile' => '../styles.css',
]);
try{
return $pdf->render();
}  catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception($e, 500);
}
```

Error:

```
"name": "PHP Notice",
"message": "Undefined index: l",
"code": 8,
"type": "yii\\base\\ErrorException",
"file": "..vendor\\mpdf\\mpdf\\src\\Mpdf.php",
"line": 20167,
```

[Sample HTML response before getting it into PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVA5u.png)

Html closing and opening tags also looks fine.

Comment: The error message is relatively clear: In your content, you try to access an index `l` of an array which does not exist. Check for that in your template/page/whatever you're trying to render. A PHP Notice does not suspend the code execution and might not be shown properly depending on your configuration.

Comment: Which version of package